# CLR DateTime object comparison with SQL Server DateTime

Tags: datetime, stored-procedures, jqgrid, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I'm using [this implementation](http://codefucius.blogspot.ca/2012/11/implementing-jqgrid-search.html) to conduct server side searching using Entity Framework for jqGrid. The issue that I'm having is that although the search is working fine for text or numerical fields, searching using DateTime values isn't working.

The problem is that the DateTime object in my model class sends the string representation of the object (i.e. in the format `2/9/2014 12:00:00 AM`) to the database but the database is formatted as `2014-09-03 00:00:00:000`. As a result, the comparison always fails.

I can't change my DateTime property to a string so I'm stumped. The resultset is returned via a stored procedure (a simple SELECT * FROM [TableName]) so I tried formatting the associated Date field and returning that but it returns as an nvarchar.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any recommendations as to how to resolve this issue? I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide an answer for anyone who comes across this. I took the following steps to resolve this issue:

1) Made the following change in the JQGrid support class:

```
_formatObjects.Add(parseMethod.Invoke(props[rule.field], new object[] { rule.data }));
```

to

```
_formatObjects.Add(parseMethod.Invoke(props[rule.field], new object[] { (parseMethod.ReturnType.FullName == "System.DateTime" && rule.data != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")).ToString() : rule.data }));
```

2a) In my controller, I added the following bit of code whenever I was fetching directly from the table (you have to specify the column names explicitly to truncate the time portion):

```
//For matching date instead of datetime values
if (wc.Clause.Contains("Date"))
{
    wc.Clause = wc.Clause.Replace("DeliveryDate", "DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DeliveryDate)");
}
results = results.Where(wc.Clause, wc.FormatObjects);
```

2b) If the data was being returned from a stored procedure, I just returned an appropriate Date field from the SP (this approach will work for DateTime fields only if the timestamp portion is all zeros).

Hope this helps someone else.